# Eclipse Recognizes Todo in FreeMarker Template File

Tags: eclipse, configuration, freemarker

When editing Java code in Eclipse IDE, I can put `// TODO` in the code and Eclipse IDE will add the comment text into my Eclipse IDE Tasks window.

When editing XML files in Eclipse IDE, I can put `<!-- TODO`...`-->` in the file and Eclipse IDE will add the comment text into my Eclipse IDE Tasks window.

I am editing a FreeMarker FTL file in Eclipse IDE.  I have installed the FreeMarker plugin.  I am using the FreeMarker editor that comes with the plugin.  The FTL file has HTML and FreeMarker tags.  What can I put in the file to have the text show up in my Eclipse IDE Tasks window?  Is there a configuration change I can make to Eclipse IDE to cause it to recognize the TODO?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just using the plain text editor then there is nothing you can type.

However you can use 'Edit > Add Task...' to add a task (you can also right click on the left hand vertical ruler and select 'Add Task...').

A Task marker will be added in the left hand vertical ruler, the tooltip for this will show your text. The marker will also appear in the Tasks view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I changed the question to mention that I am using the FreeMarker plugin and the editor that comes with it.  Your answer still applies and it may still be the only way to add a task.